# Java library that converts latitude/longitude to MGRS coordinates and vice versa?

Tags: java, latitude-longitude

I'm wondering what kind of libraries exist (licensed or not) where I may find the methods to convert between latitude/longitude coordinates and military grid reference system (mgrs) coordinates. I'm not explicitly looking for a lat/long to UTM converter, it has to be mgrs. I've done some searching and googling and from what I've found, lat/long to UTM frequently shows up, but it seems like nobody has got the library for converting lat/long to MGRS and vice versa.

Does anyone know of any libraries or places where I can find libraries that will do such a thing?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

tf.rz

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but I'll add some more for posterity.  JCoords has an MGRS point conversion, but it requires a small licensing fee.  Another source is NASA's WorldWind project (similar to Google Earth), which converted the old GeoTrans API created by NGA.  This is the implementation of the MGRS conversion: [MGRSCoordConverter.java](http://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn/trunk/WorldWind/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/geom/coords/MGRSCoordConverter.java)

Comment: This wasn't very useful since you actually need the entire World Wind library (which in turn has dependencies on AWT and other libs) and the project has it's own custom logging code embedded into some of these functions.  I ripped all of that out and provided the code on GitHub: https://github.com/Berico-Technologies/Geo-Coordinate-Conversion-Java .  I should also add that this is truly open source with a friendly license.

Comment: Super old post, but I think going forward people ought to read your answer first since I think my answer to my own question was very specific to my own case. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardClayton you dont actually need the whole library. There is a small set of code that you can use from their library that will do the job without needing the whole thing. Their license is pretty laid back also, reference: https://github.com/Berico-Technologies/Geo-Coordinate-Conversion-Java

Answer (score 3):

I've found a library called OpenMap in the library com.bbn.openmap.proj.coords they have a class called mgrs point. Props to a few questions on stackoverflow for providing various answers. I've been unable to find the question in this answer, but it got me the answer I was looking for: openmap! However, the latitude longitude conversion to mgrs points seems to be faulty, but the reverse works perfectly fine; and that's what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Another post for posterity, since my search turned up this page as well. There's a Java coordinate conversion class that includes MGRS as well as UTM and lat/lon described and downloadable here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-coordconvert/

A note says, "The download also includes MGRS methods, but conversion from MGRS is incorrect." Perhaps it would serve as a starting point and be fixable.

Answer (score 1):

I developed the following (admittedly javascript) functions combining bits from two primary sources plus others on the internet. I have optimised them for speed not understanding!

My two primary sources were:
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-utm-mgrs.html
[http://home.hiwaay.net/~taylorc/toolbox/geography/geoutm.html](http://home.hiwaay.net/%7Etaylorc/toolbox/geography/geoutm.html)

Example usage : MGRSString (51.172,-1.779) returns
"30U WB 85358 69660"

```
function MGRSString (Lat, Long)
{ 
if (Lat < -80) return 'Too far South' ; if (Lat > 84) return 'Too far North' ;
var c = 1 + Math.floor ((Long+180)/6);
var e = c*6 - 183 ;
var k = Lat*Math.PI/180;
var l = Long*Math.PI/180;
var m = e*Math.PI/180;
var n = Math.cos (k);
var o = 0.006739496819936062*Math.pow (n,2);
var p = 40680631590769/(6356752.314*Math.sqrt(1 + o));
var q = Math.tan (k);
var r = q*q;
var t = l - m;
var u = 1.0 - r + o;
var v = 5.0 - r + 9*o + 4.0*(o*o);
var w = 5.0 - 18.0*r + (r*r) + 14.0*o - 58.0*r*o;
var x = 61.0 - 58.0*r + (r*r) + 270.0*o - 330.0*r*o;
var y = 61.0 - 479.0*r + 179.0*(r*r) - (r*r*r);
var z = 1385.0 - 3111.0*r + 543.0*(r*r) - (r*r*r);
var aa = p*n*t + (p/6.0*Math.pow (n,3)*u*Math.pow (t,3)) + (p/120.0*Math.pow (n,5)*w*Math.pow (t,5)) + (p/5040.0*Math.pow (n,7)*y*Math.pow (t,7));
var ab = 6367449.14570093*(k - (0.00251882794504*Math.sin (2*k)) + (0.00000264354112*Math.sin (4*k)) - (0.00000000345262*Math.sin (6*k)) + (0.000000000004892*Math.sin (8*k))) + (q/2.0*p*Math.pow (n,2)*Math.pow (t,2)) + (q/24.0*p*Math.pow (n,4)*v*Math.pow (t,4)) + (q/720.0*p*Math.pow (n,6)*x*Math.pow (t,6)) + (q/40320.0*p*Math.pow (n,8)*z*Math.pow (t,8));
aa = aa*0.9996 + 500000.0;
ab = ab*0.9996; if (ab < 0.0) ab += 10000000.0;
var ad = 'CDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXX'.charAt (Math.floor (Lat/8 + 10));
var ae = Math.floor (aa/100000);
var af = ['ABCDEFGH','JKLMNPQR','STUVWXYZ'][(c-1)%3].charAt (ae-1);
var ag = Math.floor (ab/100000)%20;
var ah = ['ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUV','FGHJKLMNPQRSTUVABCDE'][(c-1)%2].charAt (ag);
function pad (val) {if (val < 10) {val = '0000' + val} else if (val < 100) {val = '000' + val} else if (val < 1000) {val = '00' + val} else if (val < 10000) {val = '0' + val};return val};
aa = Math.floor (aa%100000); aa = pad (aa);
ab = Math.floor (ab%100000); ab = pad (ab);
return c + ad + ' ' + af + ah + ' ' + aa + ' ' + ab;
};
```

To convert back from mgrs to lat long use the following function. The input string must have metre (i.e. 5 digit) easing and northing resolution and have spaces as output by the above function.

```
function LatLongFromMGRSstring (a) 
{
var b = a.trim();
b = b.match(/\S+/g);
if (b == null || b.length != 4) return [false,null,null];
var c = (b[0].length < 3) ? b[0][0] : b[0].slice(0,2);
var d = (b[0].length < 3) ? b[0][1] : b[0][2];
var e = (c*6-183)*Math.PI / 180;
var f = ["ABCDEFGH","JKLMNPQR","STUVWXYZ"][(c-1) % 3].indexOf(b[1][0]) + 1;
var g = "CDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXX".indexOf(d);
var h = ["ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUV","FGHJKLMNPQRSTUVABCDE"][(c-1) % 2].indexOf(b[1][1]);
var i = [1.1,2.0,2.8,3.7,4.6,5.5,6.4,7.3,8.2,9.1,0,0.8,1.7,2.6,3.5,4.4,5.3,6.2,7.0,7.9];
var j = [0,2,2,2,4,4,6,6,8,8,0,0,0,2,2,4,4,6,6,6];
var k = i[g];
var l = Number(j[g]) + h / 10;
if (l < k) l += 2;
var m = f*100000.0 + Number(b[2]);
var n = l*1000000 + Number(b[3]);
m -= 500000.0;
if (d < 'N') n -= 10000000.0;
m /= 0.9996; n /= 0.9996;
var o = n / 6367449.14570093;
var p = o + (0.0025188266133249035*Math.sin(2.0*o)) + (0.0000037009491206268*Math.sin(4.0*o)) + (0.0000000074477705265*Math.sin(6.0*o)) + (0.0000000000170359940*Math.sin(8.0*o));
var q = Math.tan(p);
var r = q*q;
var s = r*r;
var t = Math.cos(p);
var u = 0.006739496819936062*Math.pow(t,2);
var v = 40680631590769 / (6356752.314*Math.sqrt(1 + u));
var w = v;
var x = 1.0 / (w*t); w *= v;
var y = q / (2.0*w); w *= v;
var z = 1.0 / (6.0*w*t); w *= v;
var aa = q / (24.0*w); w *= v;
var ab = 1.0 / (120.0*w*t); w *= v;
var ac = q / (720.0*w); w *= v;
var ad = 1.0 / (5040.0*w*t); w *= v;
var ae = q / (40320.0*w);
var af = -1.0-u;
var ag = -1.0-2*r-u;
var ah = 5.0 + 3.0*r + 6.0*u-6.0*r*u-3.0*(u*u)-9.0*r*(u*u);
var ai = 5.0 + 28.0*r + 24.0*s + 6.0*u + 8.0*r*u;
var aj = -61.0-90.0*r-45.0*s-107.0*u + 162.0*r*u;
var ak = -61.0-662.0*r-1320.0*s-720.0*(s*r);
var al = 1385.0 + 3633.0*r + 4095.0*s + 1575*(s*r);
var lat = p + y*af*(m*m) + aa*ah*Math.pow(m,4) + ac*aj*Math.pow(m,6) + ae*al*Math.pow(m,8);
var lng = e + x*m + z*ag*Math.pow(m,3) + ab*ai*Math.pow(m,5) + ad*ak*Math.pow(m,7);
lat = lat*180 / Math.PI;
lng = lng*180 / Math.PI;
return [true,lat,lng];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I support @Richard Clayton answer about NASA WorldWind library. For those who do not want the entire library take a look at minimalized version of Berico Technologies which have extracted the MGRS conversion.  https://github.com/Berico-Technologies/Geo-Coordinate-Conversion-Java